# How to draw a figure of this complex equation using mathematica?

Tags: physics, education, mathematica-online

friends. I am learning an book and find this equation: [image]

E is the electrical field.

The book shows the figure of this equation should be this: [image]

The x axis is w0-w.
I want to draw this equation by myself. Who can tell me how to draw this using mathematica? are there some friends who can give me some guidances?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you do not know $\mathcal{E}(t)$ you cannot plot the graph.

Comment: hi,yarchik. Thank you for your reply. If I consider e(t) =exp[-(t)^2], can you tell me how to draw the figure? Thank you.